# The New York Times API

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get information of articles with The New York Times API, and I've gotten an error.
Here's the code.Can anyone tell me where my code went wrong? Thank you for your help.

```
from nytimesarticle import articleAPI
import csv
import pandas as pd

api = articleAPI("APIKey")
articles = api.search(fq={'source':'The New York Times','type_of_material':'News'},
                      value='Trump, Donald J',
                      page=1,
                      begin_date='20160901',
                      end_date='20160930')

df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(articles['response'],['docs'])
df.to_csv("nyt.csv")
```

and I've gotten an error as below.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-0bf3e4cde2c5> in <module>
      9                       page=1,
     10                       begin_date='20160901',
---> 11                       end_date='20160930')
     12 
     13 df=pd.io.json.json_normalize(articles['response'],['docs'])

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in search(self, response_format, key, **kwargs)
    109 
    110         url = '%s%s?%sapi-key=%s' % (
--> 111             API_ROOT, response_format, self._options(**kwargs), key
    112         )
    113 

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in _options(self, **kwargs)
     82         for k, v in kwargs.items():
     83             if k is 'fq' and isinstance(v, dict):
---> 84                 v = _format_fq(v)
     85             elif isinstance(v, list):
     86                 v = ','.join(v)

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/nytimesarticle.py in _format_fq(d)
     67                     d[k] = ' '.join(map(lambda x: '"' + x + '"', v))
     68                 else:
---> 69                     d[k] = '"' + v + '"'
     70             values = []
     71             for k,v in d.items():

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Comment: Just to clarify: This is a 3rd party wrapper to simplify access to the NYT API, right? I notice that NYTimesArticleAPI is from 2014, and that there now is NYTimesArticleAPInew; perhaps try the new wrapper?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica It looks like a python 2.7 vs Python 3.x transition problem to me.